# Hash or prefix all CSS class names in a Vue CLI project to avoid class inheritance

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, css-modules

I need to hash (or just `prefix_`) all CSS class names in a Vue CLI project to avoid class inheritance when I embed the app inside an existing HTML page.

Basically the Vue app/widget I've made uses some CSS class names like `.title`, `.container`, `.date`, `.location` etc, and the problem I've got is that the global CSS on the website where I'm embedding this Vue app already uses the class names `.title`, `.container` etc, so it's applying those styles to my Vue app as well. I just want a simple way — maybe using `vue.config.js` — to instruct webpack to randomly hash or prefix the CSS class names so that they are completely unique and won't inherit any parent styling. Thanks

Comment: [CSS modules](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules) might be your best bet.

Comment: I did look into CSS modules but I can't see how I'd configure it in `vue.config.js` to get it to do what I outlined in my original question. Any ideas in terms of configuration would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: CSS modules doesn't automatically patch class names in your template. Rather, it generates unique class names from  your styles, and you'd use those names in your template. e.g., from `<h1 class="heading">` to `<h1 :class="$styles.heading">`, where `$styles.heading` includes a hash (but you could configure the naming pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments above I managed to get it to work. The implementation is not as straight forward as I'd have liked because it requires changing a lot of my existing code — I was hoping for a quicker, simpler solution that would just take my existing code and hash the preexisting CSS classes — which I'm pretty sure must be possible as it seems like such a trivial task? Anyway, here's my setup for now:

`vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
  requireModuleExtension: false,
  loaderOptions: {
   css: {
    modules: {
     localIdentName: '[hash:6]'
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

`my-component.vue`

```
<template>
 <div :class="$style.myClass"> ... </div>
</template>

<style module>
.myClass {
 color: red;
}
</style>
```

Using the above setup I get a div which, *instead* of being:

```
  <div class="myClass"> ... </div>
```

is now rendered as:

```
 <div class="_2d736c"> ... </div>
```

Note the `module` attribute on the `<style>` tag which is important. Also note the class name binding: `:class` (or `v-bind:class`) not just `class`.

Hope that helps someone. Thanks

Comment: there is no simpler way of doing this? I'm using vue pug and this method will break everything.

Comment: im using windicss is their a possible way to do this?