# How to Change Class in HTML with Hash Code and Prefix in Vue 3 Project?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, webpack-4

**Question:**
I'm working on a Vue 3 project where I'm using PostCSS to automatically generate hashed and prefixed class names in my CSS files. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to dynamically change the class names in my HTML templates to match the hashed and prefixed class names generated by PostCSS during production builds. How can I achieve this in Vue 3?

**Details:**
In my Vue 3 project, I'm using PostCSS with plugins like `postcss-loader` and `css-loader` to generate hashed and prefixed class names in my CSS files during production builds. This helps in preventing CSS class name collisions and ensures better encapsulation of styles.

Here's an example of how my CSS looks after being processed by PostCSS:

```css
/* Before PostCSS processing */
.myClass {
  color: red;
}

/* After PostCSS processing */
._1x2y3z-myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

Now, during runtime, I need to dynamically change the class names in my HTML templates to match the hashed and prefixed class names generated by PostCSS.

**Example:**
Let's say I have the following HTML template in my Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="myClass">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</template>
```

During production builds, I want the `myClass` to be replaced with the hashed and prefixed class name `_1x2y3z-myClass`.

**Question:**
How can I dynamically replace the class name `myClass` in my HTML template with the hashed and prefixed class name `_1x2y3z-myClass` during production builds in a Vue 3 project?

**Some [example I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268547/hash-or-prefix-all-css-class-names-in-a-vue-cli-project-to-avoid-class-inheritan):**
***But I don't want to do like this***

***vue.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
     css: {
      requireModuleExtension: false,
      loaderOptions: {
       css: {
        modules: {
         localIdentName: '[hash:6]'
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

***my-component.vue***

```
<template>
    <div :class="$style.myClass"> ... </div>
</template>

<style module>
  .myClass {
       color: red;
   }
</style>
```

**Note:** I'm looking for a solution that works specifically for production builds and doesn't impact the development workflow.

Comment: Seems you're reinventing the wheel that Vue already provides. [scoped styles](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css), which uses PostCSS under the hood, already exists.

Comment: actually I want to global css class as well. Like col-12 should be _1x2y3z-col-12